# How to convert int array to char array

Tags: arrays, c

So I'm trying to convert an integer array to a char array in a specific style. What I want to end up with is:

```
charArray[] = "084 438 038 002 093 249 168"
```

This is what I started with before realizing that each int will be more than 1 char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void intToChar(int n, int numArray[], char charArray[]);

int main() {
    
    int i;
    int n = 7;
    int numArray[] = {84, 438, 38, 2, 93, 249, 168};
    char *charArray = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (4 * n - 1);
    intToChar(n, numArray, charArray);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     printf("%c ", charArray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void intToChar(int n, int numArray[], char charArray[]) {
    
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     charArray[i] = numArray[i] + '0';
    }
}
```

Is there a way to turn an int like 123 into "123" exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *intToChar(size_t n, const int *numArray, size_t m, char *charArray) 
{    
    int pos = 0;
    while(n--)
        pos += snprintf(charArray + pos, m - pos, "%03d%s", *numArray++, n ? " " : "");
    return charArray;
}

int main() {
    
    int i;
    int n = 7;
    int numArray[] = {84, 438, 38, 2, 93, 249, 168};
    char *charArray = (char*)malloc(4 * n - 1);
    printf("`%s`\n", intToChar(n, numArray, n * 4, charArray));
    free(charArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Here you have a bit more complicated version which will calculate how much space it needs and alloctes the memory accordingly.

```
char *intToChar(size_t n, const int *numArray) 
{    
    int pos = 0;
    char *charArray;

    //dry run
    for(size_t m = 0; m < n; m++)
        pos += snprintf(NULL, 0, "%03d%s", numArray[m], m == n -1 ? " " : "");
    
    charArray = malloc(pos + 1);    
    pos = 0;
    if(charArray)
        while(n--)
            pos += sprintf(charArray + pos, "%03d%s", *numArray++, n ? " " : "");
    return charArray;
}

int main() {
    
    int i;
    int numArray[] = {84, 438, 38, 245654, 93, 249, 168};
    size_t n = sizeof(numArray) / sizeof(numArray[0]);
    char *charArray;
    //you should check if the function returned valid pointer before using it
    printf("`%s`\n", (charArray = intToChar(n, numArray)));
    free(charArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @G.Sliepen indeed I did not chack this allocation only deleted net needed sizeof(char) which is by definition always 1

Comment: Actually, this is kind of unsafe; if `numArray[]` contains values greater than 999, `sprintf()` will print the whole number, it will not truncate it, so it might overrun the allocated buffer. Better use `snprintf()` to be sure.

Comment: Thank you @0___________ ! Just learned about snprintf

Comment: @G.Sliepen yes, it is still not safe as it will not generate the whole string if numbers are too large. Here is more complicated version as well

Answer (score -1):

`sprintf` and `strcat` could be useful.

Something like:

```
int main() {        
    int n = 7;
    int numArray[] = {84, 438, 38, 2, 93, 249, 168};
    char charArray[256];
    char tmp[32];
    sprintf(charArray, "%03d", numArray[0]); // Put first number in the
                                             // result string
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
     sprintf(tmp, " %03d", numArray[i]);  // Create a string with current number
                                          // Note: the 03 after % which
                                          // puts zero in front of numbers
                                          // having less than 3 digits

     strcat(charArray, tmp);              // Append the temporare string
                                          // to the result
    }

    printf("%s\n", charArray);    // Print the result
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
084 438 038 002 093 249 168
```

Comment: Why use `strcat()` instead of just `sprintf()`ing to the end to the string in `charArray`?

Comment: you will end with `"084 438 038 002 093 249 168 "` not `"084 438 038 002 093 249 168"` https://godbolt.org/z/a7eWGxrMf

Comment: @G.Sliepen because it is an overkill.

Comment: why tmp[32]? What system has such a long `int`?

Comment: @0___________ It's completely irrelevant whether the string is 8, 16 or 32

Comment: @4386427 so make it 8M if it is irrelevant. Bad example for the beginner.

Comment: @4386427 but your code does not produce the required string.

Comment: @0___________ Changed the result string to avoid the ending space.

Comment: @0___________ 8M is not irrelevant. Neither is keeping thing simple,

Comment: @4386427 1. Now it become a "spaghetti code" with no clear login, but with workaround. 2. It should be a separate function. Coding in `main` is not a very good practice.

Comment: @0___________ Helping a newbie is IMO about having focus at OPs problem instead of stuff irrelevant for the problem at hand. However, if you want to be "Mister Perfect" I wonder how your answer can keep the `int n = 7;` line. ohh... and check for larger integers...

Comment: @4386427 Oh Oh Oh

Comment: @0___________ Meaning of comment?

Comment: @4386427 reply to your `ohh... and check for larger integers...` BTW added version which sorts out this problem and auto calculates the size of the string needed

Comment: @4386427 We should give answers that show the OP how things should be done *properly*, and not teach bad habits. You are right about the `n = 7` and large integers, those should be dealt with ideally as well. However, your code is worse than OP's when it comes to the fixed-size buffers and the use of `strcat()`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Strongly disagree. The use of `strcat` is not a problem at all. OPs problem was lack of knowledge of `sprintf`. That's where focus is too to be while keeping the rest simple. DV as much as you like. I still think my answer is better than a complex solution that OP is likely to struggle with.